Overlapping items in custom RecyclerView Android
enter image description here
I need to overlap rows on each other, but in recycler view it's becoming difficult
Currently I can't think of any way to do this, if possible, please help me
I think this view will be a recyclerview in android

Look for StackLayoutManager or something similar in meaning ,..
